# CarrierWave cancels file upload if resize processing done

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am using CarrierWave gem to upload images. I accept any size, but when uploaded, it must be resized server side. Im using this code to do this:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process resize_and_pad: [1280, 720]
  # other things
end
```

But when I'm clicking submit on form, it simply redirects me to index of controller.

If I change `resize_and_pad` to any other `resize` such as `resize_to_fit`, `resize_to_fill` or `resize_to_limit`, nothing changes.

If I comment line with `resize` thing, all works fine except image doesn't resize of course.

In logs I see this when I have `resize` thing:

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  rollback transaction
```

And without it:

```
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "pictures" ("user_id", "name", "description", "created_at", "updated_at", "file") 
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)  
[["user_id", 1], ["name", "aaaaaaaaa"], ["description", "sssssssssssss"], ["created_at", 2016-10-01 19:37:49 UTC], ["updated_at", 2016-10-01 19:37:49 UTC], ["file", "3fe28255-f698-4f82-a64a-b41a90bb92a8.jpg"]]
(125.9ms)  commit transaction
(0.0ms)  begin transaction
(0.0ms)  commit transaction
```